# Reading from a file in C++ picks up junk

Tags: c++, file-io, io

I am trying to read strings from a file but don't know why it's picking up junk. Here's my code:

```
class book
{
 char *bname;
 public:
 void addBook()
 {
  char newName[30];
  cout << "Enter the new bookname: ";
  cin.getline(newName,30);

  ofstream add("book.txt",ios::binary | ios::app);

  if(add.write((char*)this,sizeof(this)))
  cout << "Entry Succesful";
  else
  cout << "Entry failed";

 }
 void showBook()
 {
  ifstream getBook("book.txt",ios::binary);

  getBook.seekg(0);

  while(getBook.read((char*)this,sizeof(this)))
  {
   cout << bname;
  }
 }
};
void main()
{
book b;
 b.addBook();
 b.showBook();
 getch();
}
```

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Comment: What's your input, what results are generated by your code, and what results are you expecting? Just throwing out code and saying it doesn't work with little else isn't going to get you very far. Help us help you.

Comment: Why are you opening in binary mode? Open it in input mode.

Comment: ifstream is already input mode. And I opened it in binary because the "written" data is in this format.

Comment: bname was never set to any value.

Comment: The file is in a binary format, not a plaintext format?

Comment: Your class contains a raw pointer that is never initialized and even if it was you dumping the class to a file won't save what `bname` points to. The question is tagged C++ so I suggest you use `std::string` and real serialization instead of the code you have now.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do `(char*)this`. That is very dangerous, is probably undefined behavior and it definitely won't do what you expect it to. The `this` pointer points to the entire object, not just the one field.

If you are trying to serialize the data into a binary format, this isn't the way to go about it. As it stands, you are writing and reading a pointer location. This doesn't work because pointers can (and do) point to different locations each time the program runs. The pointer location itself doesn't contain any actual useful information as far as serializing goes.

I would suggest that you not try to serialize the data at this point. Try reading/writing plaintext first.

Instead of reading/writing `this`, use `bname` directly. Additionally, you need to initialize `bname` or else it will point to junk data. Also note that it won't work if you try to just copy the `bname` pointer directly into the file. You will need to loop through the `bname` data until you reach the end to write it and likewise for reading.

You should also definitely consider using `std::string` instead of manipulating `char*`s and `char` arrays directly. This simplifies things greatly and avoids the need for manual memory management.